# Dynamically adding form elements via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have succeeded in setting up the form and making it work. However I have 2 issues:

a) The remove button does not work (it will remove the last row of the form elements)

b) and this is a minor markup issue, when pressing "add" to add a new row of form elements, instead of creating a new `<ul></ul>` it's loaded into the existing row `<ul></ul>`

Here's the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/1/

And my JS code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedSection').length;
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

    var newSection = $('#pq_entry_' + num).clone().attr('id', 'pq_entry_' + newNum);

    newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'year_' + newNum).attr('name', 'year_' + newNum);
    newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'qualification_' + newNum).attr('name', 'qualification_' + newNum);
    newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'university_' + newNum).attr('name', 'university_' + newNum);

    $('.clonedSection').last().append(newSection)

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');

    if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#btnDel').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#pq_entry_' + num).remove(); // remove the last element
    // enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', '');

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});​
```

Comment: Anyone can help me with the <ul></ul> issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your first problem, I created a `del()` function which would evaluate the number of 'rows' remaining and, if there was only one would disable the `#btnDel` or, conversely, if there is more than one row, enable it.

And then I, well, changed everything else, too.

```
var containerClass = '.clonedSection',
    containerElem = $(containerClass),
    a = $('#btnAdd'),
    d = $('#btnDel');

function numRows(elem) {
    return elem.length;
}

function del() {
    var r = numRows($(containerClass));
    if (r>1){
        d.prop('disabled',false);
    }
    else {
        d.prop('disabled',true);
    }
}

del();
a.click(
    function() {
        var rows = numRows($(containerClass)),
            lastRow = rows + 1,
            newRow = containerElem
            .first()
            .clone(true, true)
            .insertAfter($(containerClass).last());
        newRow
            .attr('id',function(i,v){
                return v.replace(/\d/,'')+lastRow;
            })
            .find('input').each(
            function() {
                var that = this;
                that.id = that.id.replace(/\d/, '') + lastRow;
                that.name = that.name.replace(/\d/, '') + lastRow;
            });
        del();
    });

d.click(
    function(){
        $(containerClass)
            .last()
            .remove();
        del();
    });​
```

The problem you were facing with the new row being added to the existing `ul` is because you looked for the last of the `.clonedSection` elements and then appended the new row to that element, rather than using `insertAfter()`.

I *think* the above revision does what you need and, hopefully, is clear enough to follow.

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Wow!! Thanks David for your time to rewrite the script. Thank you so much! I will go through the code and the references you provided as well. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome! I had a few quiet minutes, and this interested me. So thank *you*! Anyway, I hope it helps (if you need explanations of anything I'll do what I can to help out). =)

Comment: Hi David, I tried to customize your original code for the actual functionality I need which is to be used for 3 form sections. For each of these sections, the user can dynamically add rows of fields to fill in. I got it to work but gosh, with many many glitches so I supposed my method isn't right... Here's the link if you have the time to take a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/8d7Bp/3/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a solution like this to do that? http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/

It's a **mvvm** javascript library, easy to use and understand.
More information [here](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks Andrea! That looks like a great solution. I will definitely use it next time!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');
```

To:

```
$('#btnDel').prop('disabled', '');
```

'disabled' is a property not an attribute. In addition, change any other instances.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/2/

To fix the insertion issue:

```
newSection.insertAfter('#pq_entry_' + num).last();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34rYv/25/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an attribute? :)

Comment: or use $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

Comment: Straight from the jQuery documentation: Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thanks @trickyzter that seems to be the trick and thanks for the explanation too. Do you have any idea why the new row <ul></ul> is inserting inside the existing <ul></ul>?

Comment: @Iwani, you need to extract the children from the ul and append them. See above for the change.

Comment: $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', false); - not ''. .prop() uses true and false for disabled, checked, selected. Makes it more cross-browser compatible since jQuery does the work for you of deciding how to implement.

Comment: @lwani, apologies, mis-read your comment. See above for the correction.